# Create new record of new Setting Entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-uci

I have recently created a new Entity: `Configuration` of type Setting, so it won't show up with the rest of the entities. I have already updated the Forms with the necessary fields but I can't find it on the app to create new records.

Where is that form?
How can I create new Records of that entity on the UI?

Comment: Thats exactly what I explained in my answer, refer the link in there - to see screenshots. Settings is a Area in sitemap and it includes more advanced settings, but you tried adding the custom config entity as a Subarea under Extensions which is a Sitemap group

Comment: Any follow up questions?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to verify these steps:

1. Edit the UCI app to include the assets/artifacts like Entity and the Default form, Quick create form, Views, etc
2. Edit the app Sitemap to add the Entity list as navigation in UCI app
3. If you have enabled "Quick create" for that entity and a QC form is created + added as asset in step 1 - then it is better experience
4. Make the entity searchable, then you can add a record from Advanced find query results

[Learn more](https://powerobjects.com/2017/05/30/creating-custom-apps-using-app-designer-in-dynamics-365/)

[image]

[image]